# How to position submenu UL correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my menu bar I have a multi level menu. The menu is a submenu, which is an UL, under the main menu bar.

The problem is with the position of it. If I use:

```
.dropdown-menu{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Hover on Shop and then the menu looks like below:

[image: left 0 menu]

The menu is showing on mouseover. So, if the cursor is moved it goes away and doesn't look good.

If I use:

```
.dropdown-menu{
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
}
```

Hover on Shop and then it looks like this:

[image]

In this case the menu is not fully visible.

I could use the `right:0;` css but it will create the same effect to the left side menus.

Is there any way to make it dynamically visible to left or right?

Here is sample [CODE](https://codepen.io/tanzilhkhan/pen/yXwrPo) .

Comment: You can add your code or demo for this then we can help you.

Comment: @jainam I have added in the question just now. codepen link .